# How to stop CKeditor from adding a toolbar to all textarea elements

Tags: class, ckeditor, toolbar

I am using ckeditor to simply make one of my textareas on the page into a ckeditor field. I am doing this by using the add by class name method to add it to only one field. The problem is that it adds a toolbar to every other textarea as well even though they do not have the ckeditor class set on them. This is such a simple use case that I felt there would be a simple way to do it. But I have not been able to find anything among the config or in the documentation which will let me do this.

EDIT: The Code

```
<textarea id="mag-field" name="{{entry.title}}>{{ content }}</textarea>

<textarea class="ckeditor" name="{{ name }}">{{ value | e}}</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ckeditor"></script>
```

Comment: Weird - can you update your question with the code that you are using? Something's wrong here. 
If you want to replace just one `<textarea>` element, you can use the [`CKEDITOR.replace`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace) method. What you are describing looks more as if you used [`CKEDITOR.replaceAll`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replaceAll) with no class provided. Read more about various methods to create a classic editor here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed

Comment: Hey Anna, I have added the code and that is literally all that I am doing in the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
```

Not weird, the CKEditor site says this sets to false by default.